# ¿ como soluciono el error \BuildConfig.java (El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada)?

Tags: android-studio

buildconfig.java me dice **\BuildConfig.java (El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada)** y lo que ago es crear el buildconfig.java en la ruta especificada pero al entrar al buildconfig.java me dice esto: `files under the "build" folder are generated and should not be edited` y al hacer sync se me borrar el BuildConfig.java y no puedo compilar el proyecto por favor ayuda,
estoy tratando de compilar un juego de buildbox.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Modificaste algo? o que hiciste antes de que sucediera eso?

Comment: le di a actualizar el grade

Answer (score 0):

lo que podrias hacer es ver si en tu build.gradle el atributo minifyEnabled esta en true, solo ponlo en false y deberia esto solucionar tu problema. :D.

```
android {
buildTypes {
    release {
        **** Lo demas que este aca *****
        minifyEnabled false  //Ponlo en false
    }
}
...
```

}

Comment: muchas gracias por contestar pero ya lo e tenido en false y el problema persiste se auto elimina el buldconfig.java

Comment: Hola, podrias ir a File->Invalide Cache/Restart ->Invalide and Restart

Comment: hola @carlosgub gracias por comentar ya hice tu metodo pero no funciono aun me da el error tengo los enlaces en un comentario por si quieres itentar solucionarlo desde tu android studio

Answer (score 0):

talves tu puedas solucionarlo desde tu android studio este es el proyecto con el problema: https://drive.google.com/open?id=19IW0mSuFqHxhxxq-Mu-89J8UgPyfKYaa
y este es el buildconfig.java: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1YZY4KsvQHju26Lj9mb46IyRbWBWx4dsP

y si no puedes solucionarlo talves intenta hacer otro procedimiento este es el proyecto sin codificar:https://drive.google.com/open?id=1-kC6A9lxN-j2xnO15CeDns1F0jwcUcj4

si tienes suerte en solucionarlo no olvides decirme yo podria regalarte el programa de juegos en 2d sin codigo